# linear regression in R without copying data in memory?

Tags: r, memory-management, linear-regression, lm

The standard way of doing a linear regression is something like this:

```
l <- lm(Sepal.Width ~ Petal.Length + Petal.Width, data=iris)
```

and then use `predict(l, new_data)` to make predictions, where new_data is a dataframe with columns matching the formula. But `lm()` returns an `lm` object, which is a list that contains crap-loads of stuff that is mostly irrelevant in most situations. This includes a copy of the original data, and a bunch of named vectors and arrays the length/size of the data:

```
R> str(l)
List of 12
 $ coefficients : Named num [1:3] 3.587 -0.257 0.364
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "(Intercept)" "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"
 $ residuals    : Named num [1:150] 0.2 -0.3 -0.126 -0.174 0.3 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:150] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
 $ effects      : Named num [1:150] -37.445 -2.279 -0.914 -0.164 0.313 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:150] "(Intercept)" "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width" "" ...
 $ rank         : int 3
 $ fitted.values: Named num [1:150] 3.3 3.3 3.33 3.27 3.3 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:150] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
 $ assign       : int [1:3] 0 1 2
 $ qr           :List of 5
  ..$ qr   : num [1:150, 1:3] -12.2474 0.0816 0.0816 0.0816 0.0816 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:150] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "(Intercept)" "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"
  .. ..- attr(*, "assign")= int [1:3] 0 1 2
  ..$ qraux: num [1:3] 1.08 1.1 1.01
  ..$ pivot: int [1:3] 1 2 3
  ..$ tol  : num 1e-07
  ..$ rank : int 3
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "qr"
 $ df.residual  : int 147
 $ xlevels      : Named list()
 $ call         : language lm(formula = Sepal.Width ~ Petal.Length + Petal.Width, data = iris)
 $ terms        :Classes 'terms', 'formula' length 3 Sepal.Width ~ Petal.Length + Petal.Width
  .. ..- attr(*, "variables")= language list(Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width)
  .. ..- attr(*, "factors")= int [1:3, 1:2] 0 1 0 0 0 1
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "Sepal.Width" "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"
  .. ..- attr(*, "term.labels")= chr [1:2] "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"
  .. ..- attr(*, "order")= int [1:2] 1 1
  .. ..- attr(*, "intercept")= int 1
  .. ..- attr(*, "response")= int 1
  .. ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: R_GlobalEnv> 
  .. ..- attr(*, "predvars")= language list(Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width)
  .. ..- attr(*, "dataClasses")= Named chr [1:3] "numeric" "numeric" "numeric"
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "Sepal.Width" "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"
 $ model        :'data.frame':  150 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ Sepal.Width : num [1:150] 3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
  ..$ Petal.Length: num [1:150] 1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
  ..$ Petal.Width : num [1:150] 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
  ..- attr(*, "terms")=Classes 'terms', 'formula' length 3 Sepal.Width ~ Petal.Length + Petal.Width
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "variables")= language list(Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width)
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "factors")= int [1:3, 1:2] 0 1 0 0 0 1
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "Sepal.Width" "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "term.labels")= chr [1:2] "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "order")= int [1:2] 1 1
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "intercept")= int 1
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "response")= int 1
  .. .. ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: R_GlobalEnv> 
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "predvars")= language list(Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width)
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "dataClasses")= Named chr [1:3] "numeric" "numeric" "numeric"
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "Sepal.Width" "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "lm"
```

That stuff takes up a lot of space, and the `lm` object ends up being almost an order of magnitude larger than the original dataset:

```
R> object.size(iris)
7088 bytes
R> object.size(l)
52704 bytes
```

This isn't a problem with a dataset as small as that, but it can be really problematic with a 170Mb dataset that produces a 450mb `lm` object. Even with all the return options set to false, the lm object is still 5 times the original dataset:

```
R> ls <- lm(Sepal.Width ~ Petal.Length + Petal.Width, data=iris, model=FALSE, x=FALSE, y=FALSE, qr=FALSE)
R> object.size(ls)
30568 bytes
```

**Is there any way of fitting a model in R, and then being able to predict output values on new input data, *without* storing crap tonnes of extra unnecessary data? In other words, is there a way to *just* store the model coefficients, but still be able to use those coefficients to predict on new data?**

Edit: I guess, as well as not storing all that excess data, I'm also really interested in a way of using lm so that it doesn't even calculate that data - it's just wasted CPU time...

Comment: have you checked out `bigmemory` packages and similar?

Comment: @Alex: Not really. My memory requirements aren't that big. I'm talking [< 1Gb here](http://www.chrisstucchio.com/blog/2013/hadoop_hatred.html). See edit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`biglm`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/biglm/index.html):

```
m <- biglm(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length + Petal.Width, iris)
```

Since `biglm` does not store the data in the output object you need to provide your data when making predictions:

```
p <- predict(m, newdata=iris)
```

The amount of data `biglm` uses is proportional to the number of parameters:

```
> object.size(m)
6720 bytes
> d <- rbind(iris, iris)
> m <- biglm(Sepal.Width ~ Petal.Length + Petal.Width, data=d)
> object.size(m)
6720 bytes
```

`biglm` also allows you to update the model with a new chunk of data using the `update` method. Using this you can also estimate models when the complete dataset does not fit in memory.

Comment: Nice. This works really well for my purposes, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The only components of the `lm` object that you need to calculate predicted values are `terms` and `coefficients`. However, you'll need to roll your own prediction function as `predict.lm` complains if you delete the `qr` component (which is needed to compute term-by-term effects and standard errors). Something like this should do.

```
m <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length + Petal.Width, iris)
m$effects <- m$fitted.values <- m$residuals <- m$model <- m$qr <-
     m$rank <- m$assign <- NULL

predict0 <- function(object, newdata)
{
    mm <- model.matrix(terms(object), newdata)
    mm %*% object$coefficients
}

predict0(m, iris[1:10,])
```

Answer (score 2):

I think there are two approaches to deal with this:

- Use `lm` and trim the fat afterwards. For quite nice and instructive discussions, see e.g. [here](http://www.r-bloggers.com/trimming-the-fat-from-glm-models-in-r/) and [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/R/entry/is_the_size_of_your). This will not solve the "computation time" issue.
- Do not use `lm`.

If you go for the second option, you could easily write up the matrix operations yourself so that you only get the predicted values. If you prefer to use a canned routine, you could try other packages that implement least squares, e.g. `fastLm` from the `RcppArmadillo`-package (or the `Eigen` version of it, or as others pointed out `biglm`), which stores much less information. Using this approach has some benefits, e.g. providing a formula-interface and such things. `fastLm` is also quite fast, if computation time is a concern for you.

For comparison, here a small benchmark:

```
l <- lm(Sepal.Width ~ Petal.Length + Petal.Width, data=iris)
library(biglm)
m <- biglm(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length + Petal.Width, iris)
library(RcppArmadillo)
a <- fastLm(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length + Petal.Width, iris)

object.size(l)
# 52704 bytes
object.size(m)
# 6664 bytes
object.size(a)
# 6344 bytes
```