# lm fit on chunks of data in R

Tags: r, linear-regression

I am trying to fit a linear model with `lm()` in `R` on huge amounts of data (tens of GB). Is there some way of doing this without feeding `lm()` with all data at once (I am certain that my RAM could not stand that), so is there something to process the input data in chunks with `lm()`?

Does anybody know how to do this? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: see the `biglm` package, which is precisely designed for this purpose, and more generally the [high-performance task view](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html) (I don't know how to answer this with anything other than links, and it seems to be a "looking for a tool" question anyway ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25679050/linear-regression-in-r-without-copying-data-in-memory/25680625#25680625